# Javascript Self-invoke function

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, self-invoking-function

I came across the line below in Bootstrap-sweetalerts script.

```
(0, _handleDom.addClass)($text, params.textClass);
```

As I tested `it _handleDom.addClass` takes two arguments like `_handleDom.addClass($text, params.textClass)` but what is the **0** as a first parameter stands for?